# rank function only returns 1 with date in redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, window-functions

I'm running the code below in redshift.  I want to get a ranking of the order when a customer purchased a product based on the date.  Each purchase has a unique ticketid, each customer has a unique customer_uuid, and each product has a unique product_id.  The code below is returning 1 for all rankings and I'm not sure why.  Is there an error in my code or is there a problem with ranking by a date field in redshift?  Does anyone see how to modify this code to correct the issue.

code:

```
select customer_uuid,
        product_id,
        date,
    ticketid
        rank() 
        over(partition by customer_uuid,
        product_id,
ticketid order by date asc) as rank
        from table
        order by customer_uuid, product_id
```

data:

```
customer_uuid product_id ticketid date    
1              2         1        1/1/18  
1              2         2        1/2/18  
1              2         3        1/3/18
```

output:

```
customer_uuid product_id ticketid date    rank
1              2         1        1/1/18  1  
1              2         2        1/2/18  1  
1              2         3        1/3/18  1
```

desired output:

```
customer_uuid product_id ticketid date    rank
1              2         1        1/1/18  1  
1              2         2        1/2/18  2  
1              2         3        1/3/18  3
```

Answer (score 3):

First, you have `ticket_id` in the `partition by`, which makes each row unique.

Second, you are using `rank()`.  If you want an enumeration, do you want `row_number()`?

```
row_number() over(partition by customer_uuid, product_id order by date asc) as rank
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to get a ranking of the order when a customer purchased a product based on the date. Each purchase has a unique ticketid, each customer has a unique customer_uuid, and each product has a unique product_id.

Basically you have unique `(customer_uuid, product_id, ticket_id)` tuples. If you use those as a partition, the rank will always be `1`, since there is only one record per partition.

You just need to remove the `ticket_id` from the partition:

```
rank() over(
    partition by customer_uuid, product_id
    order by date
) as rank
```

Note: `rank()` will give an equal position to records that share the same `(customer_uuid, product_id, date)`.